# error: unknown type name ‘WebKitWebFrame’

Tags: c, webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

I'm attempting to build a browser with a url bar. The URL bar needs to reflect any navigational changes in the browser, and the docs recommend the use of navigation-policy-decision-requested; the callback takes 5 params, with types WebkitWebView, WebKitWebFrame, WebKitNetworkRequest, WebKitNavigationAction, webKitPolicyDecision, and gpointer.

When I try to compile, I get several errors of the variant "error: unknown type name ". This happens to all of the ones listed, except WebkitWebView. I know I included webkit2.h. I know I tried explicitly defining, by initializing a WebKitWebFrame, for example, but all it did was create more errors. Are the types not already defined? Or do I have to define them myself?

EDIT: My Wifi connection was really weak on the computer I was testing on before, so I was unable to provide code or compile output. Sorry.

main.c

```
static void uriUpdateCb(WebKitWebView* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNetworkRequest* request, WebkitWebNavigationAction* navigation_action, WebkitWebPolicyDecision* policy_decision, gpointer user_data){
  const gchar* uri = webkit_network_request_get_uri(request);
  char* file_type = strchr(uri, '.');
  if(file_type && (!strcmp(file_type, ".pdf") || !strcmp(file_type, ".db") || !strcmp(file_type, ".exe") || !strcmp(file_type, ".deb") || !strcmp(file_type, ".rpm") || !strcmp(file_type, ".dmg"))){
      // note to self: replace above if statement with a loop and a file that contains these extensions
      webkit_web_policy_decision_download(policy_decision);
  }
  else{
    webkit_web_policy_decision_use(policy_decision);
    gtk_entry_set_text(user_data, uri);
  }
}
```

window.h (controls webkitWebview)

```
g_signal_connect(webView, "navigation-policy-decision-requested", G_CALLBACK(uriUpdateCb), url_bar);
```

callbacks.h (definition)

```
static void uriUpdateCb(WebKitWebView* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNetworkRequest* request, WebkitWebNavigationAction* navigation_action, WebkitWebPolicyDecision* policy_decision, gpointer user_data);
```

Compile Errors

```
In file included from main.c:35:0:
callbacks.h:4:50: error: unknown type name ‘WebKitWebFrame’
 static void uriUpdateCb(WebKitWebView* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNet
                                                  ^
callbacks.h:4:73: error: unknown type name ‘WebkitNetworkRequest’
 atic void uriUpdateCb(WebKitWebView* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNetwo
                                                                       ^
callbacks.h:4:104: error: unknown type name ‘WebkitWebNavigationAction’
 View* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNetworkRequest* request, WebkitWebNa
                                                                       ^
In file included from main.c:35:0:
callbacks.h:4:150: error: unknown type name ‘WebkitWebPolicyDecision’
 etworkRequest* request, WebkitWebNavigationAction* navigation_action, WebkitWebPo
                                                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:29,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gioenums.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/giotypes.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:26,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from main.c:29:
window.h: In function ‘create_window’:
window.h:56:81: error: ‘uriUpdateCb’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 l_connect(webView, "navigation-policy-decision-requested", G_CALLBACK(uriUpdateCb
                                                                       ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gsignal.h:475:60: note: in definition of macro ‘g_signal_connect’
     g_signal_connect_data ((instance), (detailed_signal), (c_handler), (data), NU
                                                            ^
window.h:56:70: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_CALLBACK’
    g_signal_connect(webView, "navigation-policy-decision-requested", G_CALLBACK(u
                                                                      ^
window.h:56:81: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 l_connect(webView, "navigation-policy-decision-requested", G_CALLBACK(uriUpdateCb
                                                                       ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gsignal.h:475:60: note: in definition of macro ‘g_signal_connect’
     g_signal_connect_data ((instance), (detailed_signal), (c_handler), (data), NU
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <webkit2/webkit2.h>

// window.h
int create_window(){

  // Create an 800x600 window that will contain the browser instance
  GtkWidget *main_window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(main_window), 800, 600);

  // create the tab manager
  GtkWidget *notebook = gtk_notebook_new();

  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new ("test");

  // create the gtk box that'll set the layout and put box in window
  GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 5);


  gtk_notebook_append_page(GTK_NOTEBOOK (notebook), box, label);


  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_window), GTK_WIDGET(notebook));

  GtkWidget *grid = gtk_grid_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(box), GTK_WIDGET(grid));

  // create url_bar and add to grid

  GtkWidget *back_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Back");
  GtkWidget *forward_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Forward");
  GtkWidget *stop_connection_button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Stop");

  GtkEntryBuffer *buf = gtk_entry_buffer_new("about:blank", 12);
  GtkWidget *url_bar = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(buf);

  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), back_button, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), forward_button, 1, 0, 1, 1);
                                                            ^
window.h:56:70: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_CALLBACK’
    g_signal_connect(webView, "navigation-policy-decision-requested", G_CALLBACK(u
                                                                      ^
main.c: At top level:
main.c:107:50: error: unknown type name ‘WebKitWebFrame’
 static void uriUpdateCb(WebKitWebView* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNet
                                                  ^
main.c:107:73: error: unknown type name ‘WebkitNetworkRequest’
 atic void uriUpdateCb(WebKitWebView* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNetwo
                                                                       ^
main.c:107:104: error: unknown type name ‘WebkitWebNavigationAction’
 View* web_view, WebKitWebFrame* frame, WebkitNetworkRequest* request, WebkitWebNa
                                                                       ^
main.c:107:150: error: unknown type name ‘WebkitWebPolicyDecision’
 etworkRequest* request, WebkitWebNavigationAction* navigation_action, WebkitWebPo
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Without a look at the relevant code and exactly build output, all anyone can say for sure is those types are not known to the compiler at the point where it encountered them.

Comment: I'm sorry. The Ubuntu OS I was testing this on was having a really weak wifi problem, so I was unable to provide code or compile output at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebKitWebFrame and WebKitNetworkRequest are types from the obsolete webkitgtk-1.0 and webkitgtk-3.0 APIs, but since you are including webkit2.h it is clear that you are trying to use the modern webkit2gtk-4.0 API (as you should be). You're probably looking at documentation for the old APIs. [Here is the modern documentation.](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/index.html)

You don't need to listen to navigation policy decisions to get the URL. Just look for property changes to WebKitWebView::uri by connecting to the notify::uri signal. Look up the documentation of g_signal_connect() if you're not sure how to do this.